# build python debian package with setuptools

Tags: python, debian, setuptools

Building Debian package using setuptools.

I am working on Linux Mint 20.3. I have made a project using python and I want to build a .deb package. I have tried to follow instructions online but everytime I do something I hit a brick wall.

```
My project root directory:
- env/
- .git/
- scripts/
- src/
- requirements.txt
- .gitlab-ci.yml
- .gitignore
- setup.py
```

The internet mostly suggests using stdeb. I have apt installed all of the requiring dependencies:
python-stdeb, fakeroot, python3-all, dh-python and all others that were necessary that I do not recall.

My setup.py is very basic

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='my_app',
    version='1.0.0',
    description='My application',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=['numpy==1.24.2',
                      'opencv-python==4.5.5.64',
                      'pyserial==3.5',
                      'PySide2==5.15.2.1',
                      'pyusb==1.2.1'])
```

The internet suggest running the following:

```
python setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb
```

Which ends up in an error:

```
python3 setup.py install --force --root=debian/python3-lp5x-factory-app --no-compile -O0 --install-layout=deb --prefix=/usr 
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: option --install-layout not recognized
```

Internet suggests me removing from debian/rules file --install-layout=deb, as it is for Python 3.3 or below, as I am using 3.10.10. However, debian/rules file is autogenerated, I cannot remove it. debian/rules or debian/control is generated by the python setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb and not by me manually

In addition to all of this, I have some dependencies for an application as well, such as:
libgirepository1.0-dev, libusb-1.0-0-dev

Internet also suggests adding it in debian/control, which is generated by the same command as before, so I cannot manually append it. Nothing I try works, I am stuck.

All I need is to:

- Generate .deb using setup.py
- Have libgirepository1.0-dev, libusb-1.0-0-dev and other dependencies installed with it

Nothing works

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you use pybuild from dh-python for building, this looks like this Debian Bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1003252

It suggests to set `SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib`.
This worked for me on Debian 12 by adding the following to my `debian/rules`-file:

```
export SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib
```

I am unsure though, if you can also set this without adapting the rules-file.

Comment: Running this before a `catkin_make` command resolved the same error `error: option --install-layout not recognized` for me, thanks.